# Switching sheets in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently doing this `Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Value = 35`, but I want to a way to do just this `Range("A1").Value = 35`, by switching the sheet on a separate line before. I tried `Sheets("Sheet2").Select`, but that only switches the sheet it displays at the end to sheet 2.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `With` keyword in VBA to achieve this. You can turn:

`Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Value = 35`

into:

```
With Sheets("Sheet2")
    .Range("A1").Value = 35

    ' do some other stuff
End With
```

Note the leading . before Range. This means: use the object from the `With` statement

Alternatively, you could assign the worksheet to a variable and just use that.

```
Dim ws as Worksheet

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet2")

ws.Range("A1").Value = 35
```

Answer (score 9):

Here is how you do that

```
Sub a()
  Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
  Range("A1").Value = 35
End Sub
```